How to count documents inheriting permissions on site, library and folder level by powershell?
How to count the documents inheriting from a specific level like the site, document library or folder by powershell?
For example, I have a site with 100 documents total seperated over multiple document libraries.

25 documents in libraryA, libraryA inheriting the permissions of the
site
25 documents in libraryB, libraryB has unique permissions
25 documents in libraryC, in subfolderA which inhering the permissions
of the library/site
25 documents in libraryC, in subfolderB which has
unique permissions

I expect some output like:



ObjectType
Titel
Permission
Count




Site
SiteA
Contribute
50


Library
libraryB
Read
25


Folder
subFolderB
Full Control
25




here you have the files inheriting permissions,
counted by folder
$folderRelativeUrl = "/sites/yoursite/Shared Documents/YourFolder"
$folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $folderRelativeUrl

# Retrieve all files in the folder
$files = Get-PnPFolderItem -Folder $folder -ItemType File
$totalFileCount = $files.Count


$inheritedPermissionsCount = 0

# Loop through each file and check if it inherits permissions
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List "Shared Documents" -Id $file.ListItemAllFields.Id
    if ($listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $false) {
        $inheritedPermissionsCount++
    }
}

Write-Output "Total number of files in the folder: $totalFileCount"
Write-Output "Number of files inheriting permissions: $inheritedPermissionsCount"

counted by library
$folderRelativeUrl = "/sites/yoursite/Shared Documents"
$folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $folderRelativeUrl

# Retrieve all files in the folder
$files = Get-PnPFolderItem -Folder $folder -ItemType File
$totalFileCount = $files.Count


$inheritedPermissionsCount = 0

# Loop through each file and check if it inherits permissions
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List "Shared Documents" -Id $file.ListItemAllFields.Id
    if ($listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $false) {
        $inheritedPermissionsCount++
    }
}

Write-Output "Total number of files in the library: $totalFileCount"
Write-Output "Number of files inheriting permissions: $inheritedPermissionsCount"

counted by site
$TotalinheritedPermissionsCount = 0
$TotalFiles = 0

$lists = Get-PnPList

foreach($list in $lists){

$folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $list.ServerRelativeUrl

# Retrieve all files in the folder
$files = Get-PnPFolderItem -Folder $folder -ItemType File
$totalFileCount = $files.Count
$totalFiles += $files.Count

$inheritedPermissionsCount = 0

# Loop through each file and check if it inherits permissions
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List $list.Title -Id $file.ListItemAllFields.Id
    if ($listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $false) {
        $inheritedPermissionsCount++
        $TotalinheritedPermissionsCount++
    }
}

Write-Output "Total number of files in the library: $totalFileCount"
Write-Output "Number of files inheriting permissions: $inheritedPermissionsCount"

}

Write-Output "Total number of files in the site: $totalFiles"
Write-Output "Number of files in the site inheriting permissions: $TotalinheritedPermissionsCount"


Hi, what about the first script "counted by folder" if it has also subfolders. Some subfolders are inheriting and some subfolders has unique permissions. And what about the second script "counted by library", I would like to see only the unique lists and count the total items which inheriting the permissions from that specific library.

@KEM I'm sorry, are you having a specific issue you have been trying to solve and hit a blocker? I feel like you are using my willingness to help and I’m starting to feel a bit taken advantage of...

It was not exactly where I was looking for, but almost. I will select you as the best answer at this moment. If you could improve your script it would be very nice.
